Show only the first 2 bars on the Y-Axis using Chart.js?
I have a bar graph which needs to display a set of values like
Total Likes (likes on Facebook+Twitter+LinkenIn...)
Total Comments(comments on Facebook+Twitter+LinkenIn...)
My dataset currently holds Total Likes, Total Comments, Facebook Likes, Twitter likes etc)
I need the Facebook Likes, Twitter likes etc in my dataset since I need to show them in a tool tip.
So how do I limit my bar chart to only the first two bars in the group? Havent found an option when I was going through the chart.js APIs.


You can do this after the chart has been initialized using setDatasetVisibility. From the chart.js API Docs:

chart.setDatasetVisibility(1, false); // hides dataset at index 1
chart.update(); // chart now renders with dataset hidden


Or, you can set this option when you initially create the charts using the hidden attribute:
const cfg = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Facebook',
      data: data,
      hidden: false

    }, {
      label: 'Instagram',
      data: data,
      hidden: true
    }]
  },
};


